# WS-security Java Client

Tags: ws-security

I have do write a Java Client and call a webservice with WS-security. To generate the classes, I used axis.

Basicaly, I have the class Credentials, which has a user and password, the class header which contains the credentials, and another class ServiceDispatcherRequest, that contains the Header.

I tried with this code

```
    ServiceDispatcherServiceLocator service = new ServiceDispatcherServiceLocator();

ServiceDispatcherPortType port = service.getServiceDispatcherPortType();

ServiceDispatcherRequest request = new ServiceDispatcherRequest();

Credentials auth = new Credentials ("1", "xpto", "xpto");

Credentials[] credentials = new Credentials[10];

credentials[1]= auth;

Header header = new Header();

header.setCredentials(credentials);

request.setHeader(header);

ServiceDispatcherResponse response = port.serviceDispatcherOp(request);
```

but i get the following error

**Service 'service' has been configured for security but no AuthenticationRequest could be located in the Message Context. Cannot authenticate without an AuthenticationRequest.**

So I searched about the AuthenticationRequest class and i tried this:

```
    Message message  = MessageFactory.getInstance().getMessage();

    AuthenticationRequest authRequest = new AuthenticationRequestImpl.Builder().username(user).password(pass.toCharArray()).build(); 

    message.getContext().setContext(SecurityService.AUTH_REQUEST,  authRequest);
```

but I don't know how to send the AuthenticationRequest to the webservice.

I'd be grateful with any help on this.